# Does not work my command UPDATE on framework FaaPz/Slim-PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

does not work my mysql commad `UPDATE`, how to fix it?

this is code

```
$mysql_query = $db->update(array('`status`' => $cache['b']['status']))
                          ->set(array('`cache`' => $packed_cache))
                          ->set(array('`cache_time`' => $packed_times))
                          ->table('`'.$lgsl_config['db']['table'].'`')
                          ->where('`id`', '=', $mysql_row['id'])
                          ->limit(1);
```

and bug is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 0' at
>   line 1' in
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/c/3/c33777c4-d67a-498e-a243-d730693c74c1/pallax.systems/sub/serverlist/vendor/slim/pdo/src/PDO/Statement/StatementContainer.php:535
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/c/3/c33777c4-d67a-498e-a243-d730693c74c1/pallax.systems/sub/serverlist/vendor/slim/pdo/src/PDO/Statement/StatementContainer.php(535):
>   PDO->prepare('UPDATE `lgsl` S...') #1
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/c/3/c33777c4-d67a-498e-a243-d730693c74c1/pallax.systems/sub/serverlist/vendor/slim/pdo/src/PDO/Statement/StatementContainer.php(428):
>   Slim\PDO\Statement\StatementContainer->getStatement() #2
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/c/3/c33777c4-d67a-498e-a243-d730693c74c1/pallax.systems/sub/serverlist/vendor/slim/pdo/src/PDO/Statement/UpdateStatement.php(86):
>   Slim\PDO\Statement\StatementContainer->exe in
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/c/3/c33777c4-d67a-498e-a243-d730693c74c1/pallax.systems/sub/serverlist/vendor/slim/pdo/src/PDO/Statement/StatementContainer.php
>   on line 535

!!! i found bug ..

```
UPDATE `lgsl` SET `status` = ? , `cache` = ? , `cache_time` = ? WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

at the end is **OFFSET 0** but I do not know how to remove it

Comment: It is not a bug. It is telling you that you have a `SQL syntax` error. Why don't you check the SQL query in a SQL client to check if it is correct?

Comment: how and where check SQL query ? I do not understand...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `->limit(1)` as it is not really necessary for your UPDATE statement.

Although it should work, I believe there is a bug with that method.